# Alert set up for TLS/SSL certificate expiration

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am looking for help with setting up alert for MongoDB Atlas cluster. Recently we saw an issue where one of clusters running on Mongo Atlas had expiration on the certs and there was an outage for the same.

Looking for help if there is a way to monitor/alert if  the cert expiration is going to happen in X days.

Looked into https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/alert-conditions/ , however could not find the relevant one.

Any pointers will be of great help ,Thank you.